# Replace mutiline String from file using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

In my file I have line like

```
String sql="select * from "+
             "emp_data";
```

I want to replace  it like

```
String sql = Query1;
```

How can i do it using perl

I was using

```
$curUrl ="select * from emp_data" ;
$curUrl = quotemeta $curUrl;
$newVariable = "Query1";
$data =~ s/$curUrl/$newVariable/g;
```

which was working for single line . Not for broken one

Comment: is it Java language?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put two substitution for to do it.

```
$curUrl ="select * from emp_data" ;
$curUrl = quotemeta $curUrl;
$newVariable = "Query1";
$data = 'String sql="select * from "+
         "emp_data";';

$data=~s/"|\+|\n\s+//g;  # Here i replace the " + and \n\s character with empty.

$data =~s/$curUrl/$newVariable/g;
print $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using this tested `sed` script:

```
sed -n '
:1
/^.*[+][ ]*$/ {
  h;
  :2
  n; H; /^.*[+][ ]*$/ {
    b2
  }
  x 
  s/[+\n\t\r]//g
  s/["][[:space:][:blank:]]*["]//g
  s/["][[:space:][:blank:]]*select [*] from emp_data[[:space:][:blank:]]*["]/Query1/
   p; x;
   b1;
}'
```

The test:

```
sed -n '
:1
/^.*[+][ ]*$/ {
  h;
  :2
  n; H; /^.*[+][ ]*$/ {
    b2
  }
  x 
  s/[+\n\t\r]//g
  s/["][[:space:][:blank:]]*["]//g
  s/["][[:space:][:blank:]]*select [*] from emp_data[[:space:][:blank:]]*["]/Query1/
   p; x;
   b1;
}' myfile.txt

String sql=Query1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

# Here, the variables $/, $^I, and @ARGV either have their default values
# or some other values that were set by code appearing here.

{
    local $/ = ";";   #local => temporarily change the value of this variable until the closing parenthesis of this block is encountered
    local $^I = ".bak";
    local @ARGV = 'data.txt';

    while (<>) {
        my $perl_statement = $_;
        $perl_statement =~ s/sql = .*/sql = Query1/xms ;
        print $perl_statement;  #This is redirected into the file.
    }
}  #Automatically restores the previous values for $/, $^I, and @ARGV.
```

> `$/`    => Input line separator (default => "\n") .  Causes `<$INFILE>` to read up to and including the character(s) specified as one line.
>   `$^I`   => If set to a string (default => undef), then makes the diamond operator *magical*, which allows you to seemingly edit a file inplace.  Any print statements will get written to a new file, whose name will be the same as the original file.  If you write `$^I = ".bak"`, then the original file will be stored in a file with original file name plus a ".bak" extension.  A blank string means no backup.
>   `@ARGV`   => The diamond operator reads from files in this array.

Sample run:

```
~/pperl_programs$ cat data.txt
String sql="select * from "+
             "emp_data";
hello word="select * from "+
             "emp_data";

~/pperl_programs$ perl 1.pl 

~/pperl_programs$ cat data.txt
String sql = Query1
hello word="select * from "+
             "emp_data";
```

Or, maybe you want to replace all occurrences of the pattern:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my $pattern = q{"select * from "+
             "emp_data"};

{
    local $/ = ";"; 
    local $^I = "";
    local @ARGV = 'data.txt';

    while (<>) {
        my $perl_statement = $_;
        $perl_statement =~ s/= \Q$pattern/ = Query1/xms;
        print $perl_statement;
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
~/pperl_programs$ cat data.txt
String sql="select * from "+
             "emp_data";
hello word="select * from "+
             "emp_data";

~/pperl_programs$ perl 1.pl 

~/pperl_programs$ cat data.txt 
String sql = Query1;
hello word = Query1;
```